# What is suitable for running a RabbitMQ client on Google Cloud and writing to a Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq, amqp

I need to pull off messages from an AMQP queue, parse and transform and write to a Firebase realtime database.

What are some suitable tools/services to accomplish this?

I'm thinking of using a RabbitMQ client running in a VM on Compute Engine and the REST API to [write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) data to the Firebase database.

Or is App Engine a better choice, or something else?